# Fokker-Planck issues

Tags: matrices, probability-distributions, partial-differential-equations

So I am dealing with the following system in paper

$ dr = (\mu r- r^3 + \frac{\sigma_2^2}{2r})dt + \sigma_1 r dW_1 + \sigma_2 dW_r  $

$ d\phi = dt + \frac{\sigma_2}{r} d W_{\phi}$

and from this people obtain the following Fokker-Planck equation for the probability density function $\rho$ of the stationary distribution.

$\frac{1}{2}[(\sigma_1^2 r^2 + \sigma_2^2)\rho ]'' = [(\mu r - r^3 + \frac{\sigma_1^2}{2}r + \frac{\sigma^2_2}{2r})\rho]'$.

I think only term that I have no idea where it comes from is the $\frac{\sigma_1^2}{2}r$ term. I think that I am perhaps missing something because of the coordinate system. Please help!

Catherine xx